# I'll buy (or I'll get, I'd like)

Tags: word-usage, usage

Does "buy" sound a bit unnatural in the following sentences:

> I'll buy all the cupcakes on the top shelf.
>
> I'll buy that chocolate one.

And

> I'll buy that red one. (Backpack)

Is it unnatural to use "buy" with a specific group of things? (I mean is it more common to use "I'd like", "I'll get", "I want"?)

Comment: The most natural and commonly-heard of the above would be "I'd like [all the cupcakes on the top shelf]." The "I'll buy" sentences are grammatical, but you would come across as quite direct and abrupt by using them.

Comment: Assuming you are in a shop, it's unnecessary to say that you will buy something because that is what shops are for! Say "I'd like [X]", "I'll have that one please", or, if you have been looking at several backpacks, "I'll take the red one."

Comment: @KateBunting so does it sound unnatural?(That is: I'll buy all the donuts.) And will it sound unnatural in this sentence: "I'll buy this blue button-down shirt".

Comment: Yes, it would sound a little unnatural whatever you were buying. As I said, the shop staff know you are there to buy something!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would say *buy* if you want to communicate that you want to buy it, as opposed to just looking at it or trying it out.

If you say "I'll buy that backpack", you're telling the seller or clerk that you don't want to try it on.  They may therefore ask you if  you're sure you don't want to try it on first.

If there's no need to clarify it, *like* or *want* is probably more usual and slightly more "warm" and polite.